# Solving 8 kyu Define a card suit Code Wars (in javascript)?

Tags: javascript

My function is listed below, but it doesn't seem to work. The deck is pre-loaded, and test uses 4 cards to go through the function. Am I missing something?

Kata Code Wars

https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a360620f28b82a711000047

function defineSuit(card) {

var x = card.split('');

if (x === '♣') {

return 'clubs';

} else if ( x === '♦') {

return 'diamonds';

} else if ( x === '♥') {

return 'hearts';

} else {

return 'spades';

}

};

Comment: `split()` returns an array, you are not accessing `x` as if it is an array, ie `x[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use substr(-1) instead split('')[1]. Both will work the same, but substr(-1) is a bit faster

```
function defineSuit(card) {

   var suit = card.substr(-1);
   switch(suit){
      case '♣': return 'clubs';
      case '♦': return 'diamonds';
      case '♥': return 'hearts';
      default: return 'spades';
   }

}
```

"switch" fits better for this porpuse than "if/else". But remeber to use "breaks" if you are not returning a value after each case.